# How do I accept credit cards using the Guest Checkout option? PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

In my website I'm trying to accept payments using PayPal, But to complete payment requires sign up form users`Create an Account`. **How to enable Guest Checkout option?**

1. In my business account: I enabled: `PayPal account optional: ON`

But still no button ***Pay with debit or credit card*** `example`>[image: Pay with debit or credit card]
**Example:**

[PayPal test Payment](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes?token=1BB02167A4353603C&useraction=commit&mfid=1561299326322_f7a727c2a473a#/checkout/multistepsignup/multistepsignupaddcard)

Answer (score 0):

1.Just try once by clearing cache
2.Even if the issue persists please connect with Customer Support they will help you with this.